# Magento 2: Fetching last generated invoice

Tags: magento-2.2.1

In Magento 1, I can fetch the invoice details like,

```
$orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$invoiceCollection = $orderObject->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach($invoiceCollection as $invoice):
    $invoiceId =  $invoice->getId();
endforeach;
```

**How can I do the same in Magento 2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to inject Sales Collection Factory class,

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
.......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->order = $order;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


 public function getInvoiceDetails($order_id){

   $orderdetails = $this->order->load($order_id); 
   $orderdetails->getGrandTotal(); //you can get the grandtotal like this
    foreach ($orderdetails->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice)
        {
            $invoice_id = $invoice->getIncrementId();
        }
  }
```

and then you can use the function `getInvoiceDetails` in your template file

Comment: By order id, I  meant the entity_id, not the increment id. I cant find any function to load by order id in Magento\Sales\Model\Order. May be we can use load($order_id)?

Comment: Check the updated answer to load the order by order id instead of increment id

Comment: I believe it is `$this->order->create()->load($order_id);` and not `$this->order->load($order_id);`

Comment: no its correct only

Comment: I got blank value in the observer when creating the invoice (Magento 2.3.2)